# Integral of a Inverse Wishart Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Suppose I am given a pdf of a [Inverse Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution) as follows.

$$P = \frac{|\Phi|^{(v/2)}}{(2\pi)^{(vp/2)} \Gamma_p(v/2)} |\Sigma|^{-((v+p+1)/2)} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(\Phi \Sigma^{-1})\right\}$$

How can I integrate over $\Sigma$? That is I want to get $\int_\Sigma P \, d\Sigma$

I don't know how to integrate over a matrix. Can someone help please, or give some references, please?

As per the wiki link and the description in the Conjugate distribution section in the page, I should be getting an answer similar to the marginalized $P(X\mid\Phi, v)$ equation right?

Comment: Here's a possibly simpler example where the question is the same:

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_gamma_function) characterizes the multivariate gamma function by
$$
\Gamma_p(a) = \int\limits_{S\,>\,0} \exp(-\operatorname{tr}S) |S|^{a-(p+1)/2} \, dS
$$
where I take $S>0$ to mean $S$ is a positive-definite symmetric real matrix.

What measure on the space $S>0$ is $dS\text{ ?} \qquad$